# Is it possible to NOT trigger Firebase MFA on every login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to add multi-factor authentication (via SMS) on my React application which is already using Firebase for authentication.

I **successfully** implemented MFA by following the [step by step tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor) and I have a functional login flow with MFA.

However, MFA seems to be triggered on **every login**, which is definitely a terrible experience for users (we are using tab-scoped sessions, so each time you open the app, you have to log in again), and comes at the cost of 0.06$ per verification.
I searched through a lot of documentation, but was unable to find any information about this.

Is it possible to have some kind of control on how much time a SMS verification will be considered valid ?

If not, is there some workaround available ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well, stop using tab-scoped sessions. This is the best solution unless you're working on a banking system.